# Regex for int Array

Tags: java, arrays, regex

I need to validate a string argument if it can be converted to an int Array.

```
String pattern = "(\\d+[,])+";
String test = "18,32,5,8,10";

test2.matches(pattern2) //returns false as i requires , in the end
```

Is there any way to ignore last ' , '

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a group construct to specify that digits should be followed by (`,` digits) ...

```
\\d+(?:,\\d+)+
```

Comment: Yes. Now that I think about it, `\\d+(?:,\\d+)+` is indeed the right choice

Comment: Hi @hwnd , this is failing for single value  like test = "18"

Comment: Change `+` to `*` ... `(?:,\\d+)*`

Answer (score 1):

Regex for both array and single element

`(\d|\[(\d|,\s*)*])`

Answer (score 0):

This regex will work for you (checks for a "valid array") :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "18,32,5,8,10";
    System.out.println(s.matches("(?!.*,$)(?!,.*$)(\\d+(?:,|$))+"));
}
```

Checks and fails for:

1. multiple continuous commas
2. comma at beginning
3. comma at end

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
Pattern = "^\d+(,\d+)*$"

text = "10,5,10"    (TRUE)
text = "10,5,10,"   (FALSE)
text = "10,5,10 "   (FALSE)
```

Answer (score -1):

Since I don't know how to use regex and if I were in your place then this would have been my way to do so

```
String test = "18,32,5,8,10";
String str[]=test.split(",");
int ar[] = new int[str.length];
for(int i = 0; i<ar.length; i++){
    ar[i] = Integer.parseInt(str[i]);
}
```

The problem in this code if any I can see is this that call to parseInt() method must be wrapped in try-catch as it can throw NumberFormatException if your string contains value other than digit and comma(,).